# Python : Deleteing data from a JSON module file

Tags: python

I currently have this code which works fine, but I need to be able to delete data on command from the data file.

This is what the inside of the file looks like:
[[15, "TomBy012"], [10, "Badrob135"]]

And this is what my code looks like:

```
import json

def load_scores():
    with open("scores.json") as infile:
        return json.load(infile)

def save_scores(scores):
    with open("scores.json", "w") as outfile:
        json.dump(scores, outfile)
        print("Scores Saved")

def scoresMenu():
    print ("""Please pick a valid option from the list below

 1 » Load existing scores from the database
 2 » Save the scores from this session
 3 » Create a new score for the database
 4 » Delete specific scores from the database
""")

    menuInput = input(" Option »  ")

    if menuInput == "3":
        global scores
        name = input(" Input Your Username »  ")
        score = int(input("Input Your Score »  "))
        entry = [score, name]
        scores.append(entry)
        scores.sort(reverse=True)
        scores = scores[:10]

    elif menuInput == "1":
        print(scores)

    elif menuInput == "2":
        save_scores(scores)

    elif menuInput == "4":
        print("Work In Progress!")

    else:
        print("GoodBye! Thanks for trying our program.")
        exit

scores = load_scores()



while True:
    print(" ")
    scoresMenu()
```

To sum up, what I want to achieve is if a user inputs, for example, 'Tomby' it would delete the score assosiacted and the name from the file so [15, "TomBy"] would be removed. How would I implement this?

Comment: Use a dictionary and delete by key i.e the name

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question-and-answer site, but your post seems to be missing the question. Do you have a specific question to ask?

Comment: I thought I did ask it quite clearly? It's right at the bottom..  want to be able to remove indiviuals scores, so if my file was like the example, and the user typed in which score to delete which was Tomby's, it would delete only this section: [15, "TomBy012"]. The question was how to do this

Comment: Questions end with question marks...

Answer (score 0):

1. Ask the user for the name to delete
2. Iterate the list
3. Delete the item that matches the name

It might look like like this:

```
#UNTESTED
name = input(" Input Your Username »  ")
for index, item in enumerate(scores):
    if item[1] == name:
        del scores[index]
        break
```

Comment: Edit: Working! Thanks

Comment: Just don't try to delete more than one name using this logic